# Google GCP Can't connect Cloud Run instance to Redis Memorystore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm trying out Google's Memorystore. I've followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-cloud-run?hl=en) guide in order to set the example given by Google. I've created the required Serverless VPC Access connector, configured the Memorystore Redis instance with the defaults and finally cloned the Node.js client app provided as example.

After deploying the Cloud Run instance with the IP and Port provided by the Memorystore instance, the service responds to GET requests with `Service Unavilable` because the app can't connect to the Redis store.

Am I missing a step that is somehow not present in the guide (and the guides linked in it to configure de VPC and the connector)? Is there a clean way to troubleshoot this? Thanks.

To test if the instance is accessible within the VPC, I created a Compute Engine instance and tried to connect to the Memorystore through telnet and it worked, so I assume the problem is somehow related to the  Serverless VPC Access connector as it is not used when connecting through the Compute Engine Service as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/supported-environments#capabilities_and_requirements).

Comment: What's your configuration? Do you have more details in the logs? Are you sure that your VPC connector is up and running (no error)? Are you sure that you are in the same VPC and not 2 different ones (I'm talking about VPC not subnet)?

Comment: 1) I have a single VPC, default, a single Memorystore in region us-central1 and a single Cloud Run instance in region us-central1. Also I have a serverless VPC connector on network default in region us-central with no subnet configured and the IP range recommended on the guide. 2) Logs of what component exactly? 3) Yes, it shows up as implemented with a green check. 4) Yes, every component is in the "default" VPC

Comment: You may want to check out this video: https://youtu.be/BjRAO51omQs where all the steps are performed on camera. Maybe the tutorial you used was missing a step.

Comment: No extra firewall rules? And about the logs, it's about your Cloud Run instance. You got a Service Unavailable, because you have an exception in your code (you can't reach the Memory Store). But did you try to debug that? To have more detail? to narrow the issue?

Comment: Hey so I stopped trying to make Google's example work and used my own code. I check the logs as guillaume suggested and found that the app was throwing `ClientClosedError: The client is closed at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand`. 

An stackoverflow post about the error suggested that it had something to do with awaiting the redis client to connect (await client.connect()) and that part is missing in Google's example. My code does contain that part and it worked.